# [Fail]: Starting MySQL in my Ubuntu docker

Tags: mysql, docker

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-server && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-client
```

Then, I started a container, and ran:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work:

> root@5e37c0985d07:/opt# /etc/init.d/mysql restart  * Stopping MySQL
>   database server mysqld
>   [ OK ]
>   * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
>   No directory, logging in with HOME=/
>                                                                                                                                                                                                      [fail]

Please note *No directory, logging in with HOME* in the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `usermod -d /var/lib/mysql mysql` and then `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 2):

Try First to create an empty directory "mysql" at the host machine and then run the container with this directory path bind to the container directory path.
Ex:
docker run -i -t -p "3306:3306" -v ${PWD}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql "docker-image"